# Punctuation mark Quotation

Tags: punctuation

I have noticed recently in books a disparity with regards to punctuation marks around quotes. 
In one example I saw a punctuation mark (in this case a full stop) was placed inside the closing quotation mark. However, I am more accustomed to seeing the punctuation mark outside the closing quotation mark.

For example:
Mark said 'I go there all the time'. or 'I go there all the time.'

Which is correct? Or would both be considered to be fine?

Comment: Often logic requires the punctuation outside the quotes, but the esthetics of print requires it inside.  It's an irreconcilable conflict.

Comment: In this *specific* example, since that is where both the enclosing sentence *and* the quoted sentence end, every style guide I know of (both in the US and UK) says to put the period *inside* the closing quotation mark.